# Why SimpleDateFormat::format(Long) works on Java?

Tags: java, java-8

I'm a beginner on Java, and working with [Java class reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) recently. I just accidentally passed Unix timestamp(`Long`) to `SimpleDateFormat::format`, and it worked. But, I cannot see `SimpleDateFormat::format(Long)` on the reference page. Event parent class `DateFormat` doesn't have method `format(Long)`.
Since there is no method like `SimpleDateFormat::format(Long)`, `javac` should return a compiler error, shouldn't it?

Or is it converting `Long` to `Date` automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The next superclass up, `Format`, does have a `format(Object)` overload.

Not modern API design, but there you go.

Answer (score 3):

SimpleDateFormat has a method with signature String format(Object obj).
So, when you call format on SimpleDateFormat with a long value, this method is used because Object is a subclass of Long or your Long value is a Object.

Comment: You surely mean: Object is a **super**class of Long ;-)

Comment: Yes, but not directly. You have in the hierarchy : Long ->Number->Object.

Comment: Right, indirect super class two levels higher, not subclass as you have written in your answer.